# How can I rebless an object in Perl 6?

Tags: inheritance, raku

Another question might be "How do I inherit from builtin types?".

I have two questions really, but they are both from the same thing I'm playing with.

First, I can make a subset of a type when I want to constrain it further. I do that with `MyInt` which accepts anything that is an `Int`. I declare a variable to by `MyInt` and assign to it, but when I check its name, I get `Int` instead. So, what's up with that?

```
subset MyInt where * ~~ Int;

my MyInt $b = 137;
put 'Name: ', $b.^name;  # Int, but why not MyInt?
```

But, what I really wanted was a class named `MyInt` that does the same thing. I might want to add methods to

```
class MyInt is Int {}   # empty subclass

my MyInt $b = 137;
put 'Name: ', $b.^name;
```

This almost looks like it works, but I get an error:

```
Type check failed in assignment to $b; expected MyInt but got Int (137)
```

I understand what it's saying, but don't understand why I didn't get the same error when I used `subset`. That's question 1.5.

What I'd really like is the assignment of 137 to automatically turn itself into a `MyInt` when I assign it. I know that I can explicitly construct it, but it's a bit annoying that the parent class still turns it into an `Int` instead of using the type of the more derived type:

```
class MyInt is Int {}   # empty subclass

my MyInt $b = MyInt.new: 137;  # Still an Int
put 'Name: ', $b.^name;
```

I can override the `new` (taken directly from [Int.pm](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/core/Int.pm)), but I'm at a loss about change the type:

```
class MyInt is Int {
    method new ( $value --> MyInt ) {
        my $v = callsame; # let superclass construct it
        # But, how do I make it the more specific type?
        }
    }

my MyInt $b = MyInt.new: 137;  # Still an Int
put 'Name: ', $b.^name;
```

I can `bless` self, but that doesn't retain the value (and I didn't think it would and don't think it should. Looking at [Int.pm](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/core/Int.pm), I can't see how it stores the value. It looks like it relies on a built-in type and might not be traditionally subclassable:

```
class MyInt is Int {
    method new ( $value --> MyInt ) {
        my $v = callsame; # let superclass construct it
        put "v is $v";
        # But, how do I make it the more specific type?
        # $v.bless (doesn't change the type, fails return type check)
        self.bless;  # doesn't retain value
        }
    }

my MyInt $b = MyInt.new: 137;  # Still an Int
put 'Name: ', $b.^name;
put 'Value: ', $b;  # 0
```

There is a [rebless](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/rebless), but that isn't part of the chain of things avialable to `Int` or `ClassHow`:

```
class MyInt is Int {
    method new ( $value --> MyInt ) {
        my $v = callsame; # let superclass construct it
        put "v is $v";
        put "self is " ~ self.^name;
        put "HOW is " ~ self.HOW.^name;
        # No such method 'rebless' for invocant
        # $v.rebless: self.^name;
        $v.HOW.rebless: self.^name;
        }
    }

my MyInt $b = MyInt.new: 137;  # Still an Int
put 'Name: ', $b.^name;
put 'Value: ', $b;  # 0
```

Comment: 1 and 1.5 is because `subset` doesn't create a new **type** in the sense of a subclass, but merely a named **type constraint**. As for how to properly create subclasses of core built-in types, that's something I'd like to know as well... :) The last time I experimented with that, I gave up and reverted to using composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: there's also `nqp::box_i(42, MyInt)`, but this will only work for integers that fit into a native `int` (ie 64 bits)

Comment: to get around the lack of nqp::box_I, we can use nqp::add_I or anything similar: `use nqp; class MyInt is Int { }; nqp::add_I(100000, 0, MyInt).^name.say` → `MyInt`

Comment: @timotimo: nice idea, giving the short and sweet `method new(Int:D $value) { nqp::add_I(0, $value, self) }`; I tried to set `$!value` via `nqp::bindattr()`, but that segfaults oO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
class MyInt is Int { };
my $x = 42;
Metamodel::Primitives.rebless: $x, MyInt;
dd $x;
```

Which produces:

```
MyInt $x = 42
```

There's probably a cleaner way of doing what you want, but I don't know what it is.

**Important update** See [Raku rebless doesn't work with inhertited classes anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845201/raku-rebless-doesnt-work-with-inhertited-classes-anymore).

Comment: That's acting globally, E.g. `perl6 -e'class MyInt is Int { }; my $x = 42; Metamodel::Primitives.rebless( $x, MyInt); note 42.WHAT'`, outputs `(MyInt)`

Comment: The `Metamodel::Primitives.rebless` call fails on raku 2019.11:

`New type MyInt for Int is not a mixin type  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1`.